# How can I make my wp-login.php the homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how I can make my wp-login.php to run as the homepage in WordPress? 
So if one types: http://www.example.com it automatically goes to ../wp-login.php

And if the user is already logged in it will go to index.php?

I've allready tried adding

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['logincookie'])){
    return true;
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/wp-login.php");
}
```

on top of index.php
and it works, only when I try to fill in the username and password nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

In your `functions.php`, you can set WP to redirect all pages to `wp-login.php`:

```
<?php
function password_protected() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
        auth_redirect();
}

add_action('login_head', 'rsd_link');
add_action('login_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
add_action('template_redirect', 'password_protected');
add_action('do_feed', 'password_protected');
?>
```

Alternately, you can also use:

```
if ( ( is_single() || is_front_page() || is_page() ) 
   && !is_page('login') && !is_user_logged_in()){ 
    auth_redirect(); 
}
```

---

**Functions**

- `is_single()` will return `true` if it's a single post.
- `is_front_page()` will return `true` if it's the homepage.
- `is_page()` will return `true` if it's a single page.
- `is_page('login')` will return `true` if it's the login page.
- `is_user_logged_in()` will return `true` if the user is logged in already.

Comment: Wow! The first answer did the trick! Thanks so much for the support!