# Make select WP pages public after making wp-login.php home page

Tags: wordpress

I made some changes to functions.php, in order to redirect all pages to wp-login.php using an answer I found here:  [How can I make my wp-login.php the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234371/how-can-i-make-my-wp-login-php-the-homepage)

I am struggling to figure out how to allow access to select non-password protected pages on my site while maintaining the need for everything else to be password protected. Prior to using the code in the linked suggestion, I had a couple of publicly accessible samples pages. Those are now getting redirected to the login prompt as well.

I tried this but I'm not having any luck:

```
    add_filter(
   'ppwp_sitewide_has_bypass',
   function ( $allowed ) {
      if ( $allowed ) {
         return $allowed;
      }

      // Add specific page to bypass
      $whitelist_pages = [ 'samples' ];
```

Thanks

Comment: `ppwp_sitewide_has_bypass` hook is from plugin [password protected page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/password-protect-page/), are you using that plugin or you just randomly copied snippet from somewhere else?

Comment: Randomly copied that snippet. I missed that was from a plugin. At a loss for this workaround. Was hoping to just bypass a couple of pages without adding anymore plugins to my site.